# How to read the image x:name in the code behind c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a Datagrid. In that, I take an Image Control in the

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image name:image1 source="">
 </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Now, I want Hide this Image "image1" and visible when needed by using this property

```
image1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

and `image1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`

but problem is, I am not able to read the "image1" name of the image control in the code behind to accomplish this.
Can anybody help me what is the best way to do this and how to read the name in the code behind from datagrid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that shows clearly how your program works (or any valid code, really...the code you posted doesn't even qualify for that), it's impossible to provide an actual answer. But, you should be using the `DataTemplate` to present a view model's data, and so the way to control visibility would be to add a property to the view model that specifies the visibility you want, and bind that to the `Image.Visibility` property in the template. You may use a `Visibility` value, or you may prefer to use a non-view data type (e.g. `bool`) and an `IValueConverter` in the binding.

Comment: In other words, you're asking the wrong question. You don't need for your `Image` element to have a name at all, never mind do you need a way to find it by name. Done properly, you can control visibility without any of that.

Comment: You can't acces any control in data template by name. In code-behind try to acces after creation a "ItemSource" on your datagrid. There you have all items you added. Now you can scan by source to find image control which you want, and set the visibility to hidden/visible. Also chceck: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29ecc8ee-26ee-4331-8f97-35ff9d3e6886/how-to-access-items-in-a-datatemplate-for-wpf-listview?forum=wpf

Comment: Just a hint: you should have a look at the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find child control directly. Below example will help you find child control and it's value from Datagrid. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-find-control-and-its-value-form-datagrid-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Converter for this problem

In your resources section of the XAML

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

Add in Image

```
Visibility="{Binding BoolValue, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

**Converter**

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

private object GetVisibility(object value)
{
    if (!(value is bool))
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    bool objValue = (bool)value;
    if (objValue)
    {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return GetVisibility(value);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}


}
```